# Is it correct? : Anytime within Friday is available

Tags: prepositions

I'd like to know this sentence is correct grammatically: Anytime within Friday is available.

Comment: Competent writers would probably *always* spell ***any time*** as two words. Most native speakers would say *"Any time **on** Friday is okay"*. Most native speakers *wouldn't* use OP's version with "available" - that would normally be *"**I am available** any time on Friday"*.

Comment: Or "I am available any time Friday"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ok.. But it would be more grammatically correct for you to say any time during Friday.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please select the checkmark beside my answer if you feel I have answered your question.

Comment: What is the checkmark? I am a new user here. I put the button of triangle in circle.

Comment: The check mark is located just below the up and down arrows.

Comment: @TrevorClarke -- Most users on Stack Exchange sites wait a day or two before "accepting an answer".  This encourages other users to post possible answers.